# OpenCV / C++ - How to use adaptiveThreshold on vector instead of Mat?

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, mat, adaptive-threshold

I have a question about using the `adaptiveThreshold` function from *OpenCV* in C++. (Here is it's [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html).)

```
void adaptiveThreshold(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, double maxValue, int adaptiveMethod, int thresholdType, int blockSize, double C)
```

After reading [this article](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/adpthrsh.htm), I am pretty clear on how this function can be used to find a good threshold for *images* (represented as `Mat` object in *OpenVC*).

My case is a little bit different in that I would like to use it only for a `vector` instead of a `Mat`. So basically I have a `vector` of `double` values and I need to find a good threshold and was wondering if there is an easy way to adapt the `adaptiveThreshold` function for that matter. I experimented with more static methods to generate a threshold like using the mean average or the median, but these don't work well in my case.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to approach this? I am guessing I would have to adjust the `src` and `dst` parameters and somehow pass my vector, but a straightforward approach to do so did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `cv::Mat` that wraps the `vector`.  The relevant constructor is declared:

```
//! builds matrix from std::vector with or without copying the data
template<typename _Tp> explicit Mat(const vector<_Tp>& vec, bool copyData=false);
```

So you should be able to do:

```
std::vector<double> vec(10, 0.0); // your vector here
bool copyData = false;
cv::Mat M(vec, copyData); // default is not to copy data
```

The resulting `Mat` will be a single column.